# Loading image outside of project

Tags: java, ioexception

I want to have a project that has some folders next to my jar file:

```
+- MyProject.jar
+- graphics
    +- image1.jpg
    +- image2.jpg
    +- paper.jpg
+- plugins
    +- plugin1.jar
    +- plugin2.jar
    +- plugin3.jar
```

Within `MyProject.jar` I have this line:

```
URL loc = this.getClass().getResource("/../graphics/paper.jpg");
```

which is triggering this error:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
    at fotofilter.filters.Blueprint.getPaper(Blueprint.java:116)
    at fotofilter.filters.Blueprint.filter(Blueprint.java:45)
    at fotofilter.FotoFilter.blueprint(FotoFilter.java:103)
    at fotofilter.FotoFilter$1.run(FotoFilter.java:55)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Am I using this properly?

Comment: I don't think that it's a system resource when it is outside of the jar file. You will likely have to find it as a Image **File** not resource.

Comment: I was just thinking that. What can I do to load the image? I probably won't know where the jar or folder is located. It could be on the desktop or in a folder on the desktop or somewhere else. How can I get the location of the current executing jar file?

Comment: Myself, I start in the user directory and often open a JFileChooser from there and ask the user to find and pick the file. The user directory I believe will depend on how you call your jar file to get it running, what directory it is started in, what it's *active* windows directory is.

Comment: But the file I am trying to load is a file that is used in the program, and not something the user(s) need to load, it should load automatically.

Comment: The user directory may be the same directory that the jar is in, especially if you're running your jar from that directory. Check it out. Create a File and see if it exists, and print out its full path. Test it out. Or print out `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Comment: When I run that I get the parent directory of the jar file.

Comment: And so then what happens if you try to use the Image as a File: `File imageFile = new File("graphics/paper.jpg");`, then `ImageIO.read(imageFile)`?

Comment: it crashes saying `javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!` I have tried `File imageFile = new File("dist/graphics/paper.jpg");` wich works, but if I run the jar from the windows explorer, it doesn't work because I am in the `dist` directory.

Comment: Create a Windows short-cut so that you can tell the jar file what the active directory should be, and the use the file path relative to that directory.

Comment: If it is a resource that belongs to your program it should be somewhere in the jar-file. This makes it easier to load the picture, deploy the application,...Why do you want to sotre it outside???

Comment: I found an option in netbeans where I can change the working directory, so I did that, and now I can use `File imageFile = new File("graphics/paper.jpg");`

Answer (score 1):

`getResource` is used to find resources within the context of the current Classpath.  Normally, `.` isn't part of the Classpath, this means that the class loader won't try and look in the graphics directory

`getResource` won't be able to find these resources, unless, `.` is part of the class path.

`getResource` will prefix each Classpath element to the path, this means, unless `.` is part of the Classpath, `getResource` will not work.  In this case, you should try using `File` instead

Comment: When I had the images inside the jar file it was `/util/media/paper.jpg` which works fine. It would go to the root of the project and find it from there. Why wouldn't what I have do the same thing? Also, `graphics/paper.jpg` doesn't work either

Comment: Essentially because these are external resources and not embedded resources, getResource only acts on elements within the current classpath